# vis graph2d y-axis ints only

Tags: javascript, graph, 2d, vis.js

Is there a way to make the y-axis **only** have integer-based tick marks. This would be a tremendous help. Also, if the tick marks could be only at multiples of

```
2 when 0 <= window height <= 10
10 when 10 < window height <= 100
100 window height < 100
```

... that would be nice - though not absolutely necessary. Sorry for the pseudo-code.

Right now I am doing the following and it works ok, but it is not great.

```
this.dataset = new vis.DataSet();
var options = {
    start: vis.moment(),
    end: vis.moment().add(50, 'seconds'),
    showMajorLabels: false,
    zoomable: true,
    dataAxis: {
        left: {
            range: {
                min: 0
            }
        },
    }
    style: 'bar',
    drawPoints: false,
}
this.graph = new vis.Graph2d(container/*assume I made it :)*/, this.dataset, options);

//+~~~~~~~~~~+
//| LATER ON |
//+~~~~~~~~~~+

range = this.graph.getWindow();
var current = this.dataset.get({
    filter: function(item) {
        return item.x > range.start && item.x < range.end;
    }
});
var maxY = 0;
for (var i = 0, currentLen = current.length; i < currentLen; i++) {
    if (current[i].y > maxY) {
        maxY = current[i].y;
    }
}
maxY = maxY < 8 ? Math.floor((maxY + 4) / 4) * 4 : Math.floor((maxY + 6) / 6) * 6; // makes tick marks at places that don't cause decimal values @_@
this._graph.setOptions({
    dataAxis: {
        left: {
            range: {
                max: maxY,
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Quick note: the line `maxY = maxY < 8 ? ...` only works for 1-11 from what I can test. I am not sure about higher numbers. However, hopefully this can be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Very very late answer, but assuming you only care about the y-axis labels themselves and not the horizontal grid lines, you can do this:

```
var options = {
    dataAxis: {
        left: {
            format: function(value){
                // don't show non-integer values on data axis
                return Math.round(value) === value ? value : "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also access `window.height` in that function and adjust accordingly for the behaviors you described.

Comment: Cool thanks for you input. This was so long ago I have lost sight of what exactly the intent was, but thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems like the method I implemented works (e.g. I only see whole numbers regardless of the y value) if you want ints only and don't mind (or want) the minimum y value to be 4 and, additionally, don't mind what the step is.

However, note that this has only been tested with [0, inf) (positive, numbers or 0).

If you have a solution that uses vis to do this - rather than checking for all of the max y values manually - please do share in an *answer*.